# Launch a GNOME session from a remote terminal

Tags: linux, ssh, gnome, xorg

I'm sshing into my friend's machine and I'm wondering how I would launch a GNOME session over SSH.  I need to open a web browser on his machine to view something which can only be done from his hostname.  What's the easiest way to achieve this via SSH?

Answer (score 13):

Switch to a second terminal, for example tty2: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd>, login and start a new X session on an available display:

```
xinit -- :1
```

Now ssh to the other machine, enabling X forwarding (or trusted X forwarding with `-Y`):

```
ssh -X user@machine
```

Once logged in, start a new gnome-session:

```
gnome-session
```

You can also pass `gnome-session` as a command to `ssh`.

Answer (score 8):

If all you need to do is run a web session, appearing to come from your friend's computer, I'd suggest just running OpenSSH with the ssh -D8888 argument (8888 is just an example), and set up your local browser to point to localhost:8888 as a SOCKS5 proxy.

If you must run a browser over the link, there's no reason why you need to start up an entire GNOME session, just run ssh -X as described in the other questions, and then run the browser alone.

Answer (score 4):

To launch `gnome` from terminal use the command `startx`.

Comment: Nope. .xinitrc has to be set up for that,

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ssh -X` or `ssh -Y` to his machine to run apps on your friend's machine but using your Xorg. The web browser will still be making the connection from his hostname.

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu, I use these commands:

> ssh -X user@host gnome-session

or

> ssh -Y user@host gnome-session

Answer (score 1):

I found the x11vnc to be pretty easy.

Allowed me to see the remote active gnome desktop.

(Appears as a desktop app. I ssh-tunnel forward it's port on my local machine. Then connect my local vnc client to my local ssh-forwarded port.)